# EF Code First and Saving Multiple Records

Tags: entity-framework

Just getting to grips with Entity Framework and I can save, add, delete etc a single entity like so:

```
db.Entry(client).State = EntityState.Modified;
db.SaveChanges();
```

My question is if I wanted to change several records how should I do this, for example I want to select all Jobs with a Type of 'new' and set the Type to 'complete'.  I can select all the jobs easily enough with Linq but do I have to loop through, change them, set the state to modified, save changes, next one etc?  I'm sure there is a straightforward way that I just don't know about or managed to find yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure you need to set the EntityState?  SaveChanges will DetectChanges before saving.  You can't update multiple records at once as you are requesting, but you can loop through, update the value and call save changes after the loop.  This will cause 1 connection to the database where all of your updated records will be saved at once.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you would have to loop through each object, but you don't have to save changes after each one.  You can save changes after all the changes have been made and update in a single go.  Unless there is some reason you need to save before editing the next record.

However, if you have a simple operation like that, you can also just issue a SQL statement to do it.

```
context.Table.SqlQuery("UPDATE table set column = 1 where column2 = 3");
```

Obviously, that more or less bypasses the object graph, but for a simple batch statement there's nothing wrong with doing that.